# Solving the system of linear homogeneneous differential equations.

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, systems-of-equations

I have stumbled upon quite a strange issue, while solving the following system of differential equations:
$$ \left\{\begin{matrix}
\; \dot{x} &=&2x+6y-15z \\ 
\; \dot{y} &=&x+y-5z \\
\; \dot{z} &=&x+2y-6z
\end{matrix}\right. \left |A=\begin{pmatrix}
2 & 6 & -15 \\
1 & 1 & -5 \\
1 & 2 & -6 \\ 
\end{pmatrix}\right. \left\|\dot{f} = Af, f = \begin{pmatrix}
x\\
y\\
z\\
\end{pmatrix}.\right.$$
Getting eigenvalues for the matrix $A$, I got that $|A-\lambda I| = 0 \Leftrightarrow (\lambda + 1)^{3} = 0.$ That is the Characteristic equation has only one solution (the matrix has only one eigenvalue), s.t. $mult(\lambda_{1} = -1) = 3.$

Thus, I have had to find the eigenvectors, gotten this eigenvalue I got that:

I. $\lambda = -1:$

$(A-\lambda I) = \left(\begin{array}{ccc|c}
3 & 6 & -15 & 0\\
1 & 2 & -5 & 0\\
1 & 2 & -5 & 0\\ 
\end{array}\right) \xrightarrow[]{\text{RREF}} \left(\begin{array}{ccc|c}
1 & 2 & -5 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\ 
\end{array}\right),$ thus $v_{\lambda} = 
\begin{pmatrix}
5c-2b\\
b\\
c\\
\end{pmatrix}.$ For some $a, b\in\mathbb{C}$, i.e. the eigenvectors of A are:
$$
\tilde{e}_{1} = \begin{pmatrix}
5\\
0\\
1\\
\end{pmatrix}, \tilde{e}_{2} = \begin{pmatrix}
-2\\
1\\
0\\
\end{pmatrix},\mathbb{E_{\lambda}} = \left\{\tilde{e}_{1}, \tilde{e}_{2}\right\}.$$
Now, as $|\mathbb{E_{\lambda}}| = 2$, we have to create a joint vector: $\tilde{e}_3 = v^{(1)}_{\lambda}$, but I don't know, what should I do there, in order to obtain $\tilde{e}_3$, as we have TWO eigenvectors, corresponding to one eigenvalue. If I pick $v_{\lambda}$ with $b = c = 1$ , then the joint vector $v^{(1)}_{\lambda}$, s.t. $(A-\lambda I)\cdot v^{(1)}_{\lambda} = v_{\lambda}$, is:
$$v^{(1)}_{\lambda} =  \begin{pmatrix}
4\\
1\\
1\\
\end{pmatrix}, v^{m}_{\lambda} = \left(v_{\lambda} \cdot t + v^{(1)}_{\lambda}\right)$$
However, when I derive that:
$$ f = e^{-t}\left(\tilde{C}_1\cdot\tilde{e}_{1}+ \tilde{C}_2\cdot\tilde{e}_{2}+ \tilde{C}_3\cdot  v^{m}_{\lambda}\right)$$
And then check the result, assuming that $\tilde{C}_1 = 1, \tilde{C}_2 = 2, \tilde{C}_1 = 3$, I got that $\dot{x} = (-6e^{-t}-9e^{-t}t)$, however, by $f$ it should be $(-4e^{-t}-9e^{-t}t).$

I just really want to understand, what am I mistaken in? I have tried to reach my course teacher, but he doesn't seem to respond, so I decided to post my question there.

Thank you in advance for the help!

Comment: Choose your basis so that $A$ is in Jordan normal form.

Comment: @user10354138 You mean, I have to extend $\mathbb{E}_{\lambda}$, such that A is in JNF? But haven't I done it, I am just quite confused..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like I have made a mistake in calculations, when checking my answer, as after recalculating it once again, I got the following: (Assuming $\tilde{C}_k = k$)

$ \frac{\partial x}{\partial t} = \frac{\partial}{\partial t}\left(e^{-t}\left(5\tilde{C}_1 -2\tilde{C}_2 +\tilde{C}_3(3t+4) \right)\right) = \frac{\partial}{\partial t}\left(e^{-t}\left(5 -2\cdot2 +3(3t+4) \right)\right) = -e^{-t}(4+9t) [LHS] = -e^{-t}(4+9t)[RHS] = e^{-t}\left(2\cdot(5-2\cdot2+3(3t+4))+6\cdot(2+3(t+1))-15\cdot(1+3(t+1))\right)$

That means, that the solution that I have provided there works correctly.